# C++ 3D model io, binary file reading (badbit) and #DEN issue

Tags: c++, binary, ifstream

I'm currently working on the base framework for my path tracer. I'm trying to create a simple binary model loader (reading and writing) but I've encountered a problem with reading back the file. To give a little more context:

Writing my data seems to be going fine i.e. no exceptions thrown and filesize seems to be good. When I start reading the data , it all seems to be going alright until some point (after reading all the vertex positions and some normals) when my data gets corrupted. When I debug all the numbers are right but it is clear that at some point I get #DEN instead of the correct float value. The same happens with all my meshes at some point, so it can be when reading UV's or triangles, etc.

(Image #DEN at 54th Normal (3rd float) ... not enough reputation)

I read all the Normals (for 1 sub-mesh) in one go. When I look at the ifstream, it resets back to the beginning of the file. When I start reading my triangle indices (a new stream.read()) the badbit is set.

I use Visual studio 2010 Ultimate and I'm running on Windows 7 Professional x64. I'm using C and C++.

I will try to show only the crucial code:

```
if(meshHeader.numberOfNormals > 0)
{           
    Normal* _normals = Read<Normal>(meshHeader.numberOfNormals);

    if(_normals)
    {
        // Copy from array to vector
        _normalsVec = new vector<Normal>(_normals, _normals + meshHeader.numberOfNormals);

        // Cleanup              
        delete[] _normals;
    }
    else
    {
        // Cleanup
        delete[] _normals;
        throw runtime_error("Failed reading vertex normals");
    }
}
```

Read method:

```
template <typename T> 
T* BinaryModelIO::Read(unsigned int _size)
{
    T* _data = new T[_size];
    unsigned int _numberOfBytes = Read(sizeof(T) * _size, static_cast<void*>(_data));

    if(_numberOfBytes != (sizeof(T) * _size))
    {
        delete[] _data;
        _data = 0;
    }

    return _data;
}
```

(static_cast(_data) is not the cause) more read:

```
unsigned int BinaryModelIO::Read(unsigned int _numberOfBytes, void *_buffer)
{
    if(isWriter)
        return 0;
    // no fail bit set?
    if(!readStream->fail())
    {
        try
        {
            readStream->read((char*)_buffer, _numberOfBytes);
        }
        catch(exception &e)
        {
            cerr << e.what() << endl;
            //return 0;
        }
        return _numberOfBytes;
    }
    else
    {
        if(readStream->badbit)
            cerr << "badbit" << endl;
        else if(readStream->eofbit)
            cerr << "eofbit" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Reading the Normals goes as expected but after some amount of floats (Normals) it goes wrong. I tried reading the whole array of Normals with a for loop and then copying all elements to the vector, but this was not the problem. When reading the Triangle data (done in similar way), the badbit is set (or somewhere before the Triangles are read). In the image below I was debugging while reading the triangles and badbit gets printed.

(Image showing print ... not enough reputation)

My data structures I'm trying to Read/Write do NOT contain virtual functions and all consist of floats (except for triangle which has 3 unsigned int's). Point(3 floats), UV(2 floats), Normal(3 floats), Triangle(3 unsigned int's).

edit:
Here's the definition of the Normal

```
class Normal 
{
public:
    // Vector Public Methods
    Normal(float _x = 0.0f, float _y = 0.0f, float _z = 0.0f) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) {   }
        explicit Normal(const Vector3& _vector);
        explicit Normal(const Point& _point);

    // Overloaded Operators
    Normal operator+(const Normal& _norm) const 
    {
        return Normal(x + _norm.x, y + _norm.y, z + _norm.z);
    }   
    Normal& operator+=(const Normal& _norm) 
    {
        x += _norm.x; 
        y += _norm.y; 
        z += _norm.z;
        return *this;
    }
    Normal operator-(const Normal& _norm) const 
    {
        return Normal(x - _norm.x, y - _norm.y, z - _norm.z);
    }   
    Normal& operator-=(const Normal& _norm) 
    {
        x -= _norm.x;
        y -= _norm.y; 
        z -= _norm.z;
        return *this;
    }
    bool operator==(const Normal& _norm) const 
    {
        return x == _norm.x && y == _norm.y && z == _norm.z;
    }
    bool operator!=(const Normal& _norm) const 
    {
        return x != _norm.x || y != _norm.y || z == _norm.z;
    }
    Normal operator*(float _f) const 
    {
        return Normal(_f * x, _f * y, _f * z);
    }   
    Normal &operator*=(float _f) 
    {
        x *= _f; 
        y *= _f; 
        z *= _f;
        return *this;
    }
    Normal operator/(float _f) const 
    {
        // One division, 3 multiplications ^^
        float _inverse = 1.f / _f;
        return Normal(x * _inverse, y * _inverse, z * _inverse);
    }
    Normal &operator/=(float _f) 
    {
        float _inverse = 1.f / _f;
        x *= _inverse; 
        y *= _inverse; 
        z *= _inverse;
        return *this;
    }
    Normal operator-() const 
    {
        return Normal(-x, -y, -z);
    }
    float operator[](int _i) const 
    {
        // Return x, y or z
        return (&x)[_i];
    }   
    float &operator[](int _i) 
    {
        return (&x)[_i];
    }

    float LengthSquared() const 
    { 
        return x * x + y * y + z * z; 
    }
    float Length() const 
    { 
        return sqrtf(LengthSquared()); 
    }

    // Public Variables
    float x, y, z;
}; // 12 Byte
```

edit2:
File opening (done when Loader object is created and destroyed)

```
bool AbstractStream::OpenFile()
{
    bool _return = false;

    // We should open file to write or to read
    if(isWriter)
    {
        // Check if the file is already open
        if(!writeStream->is_open())
            writeStream->open(fileName, ios::in | ios::binary);

        if(!writeStream->fail())
            _return = true; // File could be opened
    }
    else
    {
        // Check if the file is already open
        if(!readStream->is_open())
            readStream->open(fileName, ios::in | ios::binary);

        if(!readStream->fail())
            _return = true; // File could be opened
    }

    return _return; // File could be opened
}
```

**If I forgot something please tell me because this is my first question on stackoverflow ever.**

I really hope someone can help me because I side stepped this problem for a while (working on other parts of the renderer).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May be worth including the definition of Normal. The closer you can get this to an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) the better.

Comment: How are you opening the file? Are you telling the system that the file is binary? (ios::binary)?

Comment: I open it with ios::binary.

Comment: Personally, I would ditch the two overloaded "Read()" methods and just substitute a good old fashioned "fopen()/fread()/fclose()"  IMHO...  PS: A good SSCCE would be to read your file, and print it out as text (to stdout is fine).

Comment: I get what you mean, but the Write and Read that call stream->read() will be in an AbstractStream class for later use to serialize objects.

Answer (score 0):

Besides your antique us of new/delete (avoid pointers) I guess your problem is writing data. My suggestion: Try writing a non(!) binary file, have a look at it in an editor.

Comment: Thank you Dieter, but this is work in progress code and creating a binary reader/writer is my goal. Also, can you help me by explaining why to avoid pointers? The part where I create the normals and then delete them, does not represent the final code. For debugging it would be useful to write text, but it requires me to rewrite large parts of my code. I already created a wavefront (.obj) loader, which is text based and the goal is to have binary asset files that can be loaded fast i.e. acceleration structures, textures, etc.